# What equal installment of annual payment will discharge a debt which is due as 848 at the end of 4 years at 4% per annum simple interest?

Tags: finance

> What equal installment of annual payment will discharge a debt which is due as Rs. 848 at the end of 4 years at 4% per annum simple interest?

The above question can be calculated by using the formula $$x= \frac{100P}{100n+\frac{n(n−1)r}{2}}$$ which gives the result $= 200$. My doubt is that $200 \cdot 4 = 800$. So when will the balance $848-800= 48$ be paid?

Comment: Please read this [tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) on how to typeset mathematics on this site.

Comment: Would keep these tips in mind, next time when I'll ask a question.

Answer (score 1):

*you are forgetting the interest on the payments *

Assuming payments at the end of each year,

interest of 4% for 3 years will accrue for 1st 200 when payment is due,

for 2 years for 2nd payment , etc.

The formula you used was devised taking this into account.

You can check that exactly 48 interest would have accrued at time of payment, you have paid the dues fully !

Comment: Could you please elaborate. When we repay a loan, the installment amount already includes the interest.

Comment: That would be so if the loan due was at the start, here the loan due is given at the **end** of 4 years, what you pay in instalments gathers interest till the time of payment.

Comment: So what exactly are we paying at the time of payment? 800

Comment: No, including accumulated interest, 848

Comment: Still don't get it.

Comment: **Any** loan - payment balance has to be computed at **one** point in time.
Here we are computing at the end of 4 years.
1st payment of 200 becomes 200+12% interest = 224 at payment time
2nd payment of 200 becomes 200 + 8% interest = 216 at payment time
3rd payment of 200 becomes 200 + 4%interest  = 208at payment time
4th payment of 200 remains 200 at payment time
224+216+208+200=848 fully repays loan which was **due only at payment time.**
I suggest you carefully read your book to get a grasp of fundamental concepts.

Answer (score -2):

I also had the same problemn.My peer told me that bank receive the first payment after 1 year, and THEY **invest it at 4% interest**. So they get 3 years of interest on that .The payment made at end of first year has **3 years** to earn simple interest at 4% per year. So t will be 3 for that.

But why 3 years or why not 1 year.